# How to Open Modal from Function Call Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have this Modal from Bootstrap 
When I add 
button To call it it open successfully,
but what I really need is to open this modal from function calling automatically
my Experiment is:

```
     <button id="RenewCollerctorDateID" class="btn btn-success" style="width: 10%; display: inline;
 padding-right: 10px; float: left;" onclick="RenewCollectorDatePeriod();">renew</button>
```

MY JavaScript is

```
 function RenewCollectorDatePeriod() {
         //   AreYOuSureRenew();        
            var EmpID = $("#<%=ddlFilterCollector.ClientID%>").val();
            if (EmpID == -1) {
                alert("please select one ")
            }
            else {
               alert(EmpID);
              GetCollectorInfo(EmpID);       
            }        
        }
```

then:

```
        function GetCollectorInfo(EmpID) {
       //     AreYOuSureRenew();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "UnloadingCalendar.aspx/GetCollectorInfo",
                data: JSON.stringify({ EmpID: EmpID }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result.d);
                    AreYOuSureRenew();
                    },
                error: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg.d);
                },
                complete: function () {

                }
            })
        }


    function AreYOuSureRenew() {
        alert("opened");
        $('#EnsureModal').modal('show');
    }
```

and here my modal

```
    <div class=" modal fade" id="EnSureModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Do ypu need change </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Are u sure from </p>
                    <label id="FromDate"></label>
                    <p>To</p>
                    <label id="ToDate"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">no</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">yes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Notice: when I add `$("#EnSureModal").modal('show');` in Document.Ready it appeasrs on page load and appears again on function call , how can I make it appears only in function call

Comment: When do you call `AreYOuSureRenew` ?

Comment: Onsuccess of ajax  from another function @RayonDabre

Comment: Call the function AreYOuSureRenew();

Comment: @saraadly, please ignore my comment, I gone through your second comment above and understood your scenario well.

Comment: Any error in console ?

Comment: @RayonDabre No, it access the `alert("opened")`  and no errors in console

Comment: Can we have a fiddle of the same ?

Comment: @RayonDabre there is postback which makes the modal noninitialized, do you have any idea about how to make it reinitalizing?

Comment: Unfortunately... I can not make guesses without actually execute it... Share a fiddle...

Comment: @RayonDabre Dear, If I made Fiddle it works fine , my probelm is the page has postback , and if I call the Function before the postback the modal opened correctly , but when I call the modal after postback it didn't opened , Sadly  I didn't know how to simulate my problem on fiddle  :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109155/discussion-between-rayon-dabre-and-sara-adly).

Answer (score 7):

I read your code and I found out that you didn't use bootstrap correctly and the also the script you wrote is not correct. Check this out. This might help you.

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#fireme").click(function(){
        $("#EnSureModal").modal();
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<button id="fireme" class="btn btn-default">Fire me up!</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="EnSureModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Do ypu need change </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Are u sure from </p>
                <label id="FromDate"></label>
                <p>To</p>
                <label id="ToDate"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">no</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">yes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bbo7wdj1/1/)

Comment: But I need to fire this event in the function call, not in Document.ready

Comment: Then you may call it on the button like onclick="myfunction()" .